# answer to iq test with colored squares

Tags: recreational-mathematics, puzzle

What is the best (whatever this means) answer and why?

[image: taken from a well-known Danish IQ society test]

Comment: @Asaf Karagila:  is your tag edit meant to imply there is no logic in this puzzle?  I am inclined to agree.

Comment: @Ross, that point aside; this question is about common sense, not mathematical logic.

Answer (score 4):

Well, that's funny, 'cause you can get an answer basing only on several conventions (resonable ones). But they are not unique, so guess you can get different answers. Let's try.

 In the left column we have initial states (I've placed an axis, running along the colored blocks from blue to red). 

 In the middle colum we have the state that shows us the direction of transformations (rotations). I've placed an axis along the colored in gray blocks in such a way that it always points upwards. Plus I've added an azure line which coincides in direction with the initial state and has two parts: the inital and mirrored one. 

 In the right column we have final states which are obtained by the rotation of the initial state along the direction of transformations.

So following this logic I guess the answer is $\mathrm{G}$.

 

 
[image]

Comment: Strange in the intelligence test, the people who deal with math (which no doubt are among the smartest poeple) we partake of different answers while only one is correct.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be $F$, based on $(1,3)$ being $(1,1)$ with red and blue having switched places, and the same for $(2,1)$ and $(2,3)$. Not sure what to make of the middle column though.

Comment: I thought about that, too, but felt compelled to use the middle column somehow.  I agree this is plausible.

Comment: I, too, think that the answer is F. However, in my logic I don't focus on the pattern of colored squares. Focus on the patterns of white squares. F becomes the apparent answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is **G**. The middle column seems to represent reflection, so the blue box remains at its spot while the red one moves accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I want to say the middle column describes the location or equation of reflecting mirror.
So top is $y=-x$ middle is (questionably) $y$ axis and bottom is $y=x$. Based on this I choose G.

The problem is that the middle mirror is not symmetrically placed.

Answer (score 0):

I would say C without much conviction.  I take the black/white squares to tell me how to reflect the left column.  The top and bottom tell me to reflect through the center, while the middle one says reflect across the vertical centerline.  I think we definitely want the red and blue next to each other and on one half of the diagram, so would strongly rule out A,B,D,E, but I suspect there is an explanation for some of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the white squares, from right to left, the answer would be F cause white squares always get back to the same position, with blue/red changes positions. Is the most simple answer and make sense, so problably is the right one.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is undoubtedly B. If you consider the entire group of blocks along with their rhythm,  you will clearly see the answer. I've taken some of the most complex and in depth IQ test and have a consistent score of 192
I belong to several elite high IQ societies also. The answer to that question is simply B.

Comment: Care to explain a bit your reasoning?